# Win32 app not affected by dpi setting when hosted by WPF app

Tags: wpf, winapi, dpi

I'm launching an old win32 app as a child in a wpf app. The problem is that the win32 app ignores the dpi setting when run as a child of the wpf app. The dpi setting has the desired effect on the win32 app when launched in its own window. I've assumed that the wpf app is "dpi aware" and the win32 app becomes so when childed. I would like to get the win32 child app to be sized according to the dpi setting like it is when launched alone.

Comment: Interesting; how are you launching the child process?  And are you using the legacy "XP style" DPI scaling, or "Vista" style DPI scaling?